# How can I replace an image with rectangle of the same size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

How can I hide an image, but keep a border or opaque rectangle where the image used to be? Masking the image is acceptable too.

This has to work for images of different sizes, so hardcoding a containing div's size and setting a border/bgcolor won't work.

I guess I could wait for the image to load, get it's dimensions, and then set its containing div to the same dimensions. Is there an easier way though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image into a container and center it to mimic the image's border. Then fade out the image as you like (the `opacity` property is perfectly fine here) or set its `visibility` property to `hidden`.

This works for any kind of image, just do not set a width and height for the container. Use `padding` to achieve the desired borders.

Comment: Lots of good answers here, but I'm accepting yours for answering the border part of the question too. By the way, the container may need to be set to display:inline-block in order for it to take the same size of the image.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to retain space until the image is loaded use the [**CSS visibility attribute**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) and set the image visibility to `hidden`.

```
.image {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The image is still going to take up space despite its invisible preserving your layout from collapsing. Of course no image borders will be displayed but I am guessing you are doing this only to preserve layout from collapsing after the image is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Given a 1x1 pixel on your server at URL 'images/opaque.gif', you could do this:

```
var theImage = $('img');
theImage
    .css({width: theImage.width(), height: theImage.height()})
    .attr('src', 'images/opaque.gif');
```

Setting the width and height is necessary so the image doesn't resize to 1x1.

Answer (score 1):

Easy methods include setting CSS `opacity` to `0`, or `visibility` to `hidden`.

If you want to replace it with an element of the same size, how about

```
function hideImage(image) {
    var s = getComputedStyle(image, null);
    var w = s.getPropertyValue("width");
    var h = s.getPropertyValue("height");
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    /* do your supplementary styling, e.g. background in CSS */
    /* by default, img elements are display: inline-block;, by the way */
    d.className = 'imagecover';
    d.style.width = w;
    d.style.height = h;
    image.parentNode.replaceChild(d, image);
}

hideImage(document.getElementById('some_image_to_hide'));
```